# Is it possible to gather a free response after a particular intent is triggered?

Tags: dialogflow-es

In an application that we are building, we are hoping to implement a feature where if a customer wants to leave feedback without our chat app, we can capture the following message and use that full message as the feedback for internal user. We've tried using the fallback intent, but that didn't produce satisfactory results, as it would often just swap to another intent that would seem related based on their feedback.

Comment: How exactly do you want to invoke your 'feedback' intent? Do you want to invoke it whenever the customers say something related to giving feedback?

Comment: Ideally, yes. Saying 'give feedback' and then taking the next whole response as the feedback entry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using contexts. In your example, on the intent triggered by "give feedback" (ie `Give Feedback Intent`) set an output context of `giving_feedback` with a lifespan of `1`.

Then, [create a new fallback intent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-default#fallback) with an input context required of `giving_feedback`, and enable fulfillment for it (so you can store this feedback somewhere I presume).

Now when your user triggers your `Give Feedback Intent` then anything else, Dialogflow should prioritise the fallback intent (as it has a matching input context).

To ensure this would always work, you can put an input context required on every other intent, so that dialogflow has no option other than to use the newly created fallback intent. For example you could set up your intents like this:

```
Default Fallback Intent:
  as normal
Default Welcome Intent:
  output context: conversation:1
Some Other Intent:
  input context: conversation
  output context: conversation:1
Give Feedback Intent:
  input context: conversation
  output context: giving_feedback:1
Feedback Fallback Intent:
  input context: giving_feedback
  output context: conversation:1 // this allows the conversation to resume as normal
```

You can see that when you trigger the `Give Feedback Intent`, then say literally anything else, dialogflow has no option but to give you one of the two fallback intents - and it will prioritise the one with matching input contexts. This solution assumes the welcome intent is always triggered first to add that initial `conversation` context. If you don't do this, you will have to edit your first `detectIntent` request to send through the `conversation` context manually.